# How can I break up this py file in a DRY fashion?

Tags: python, dry

In the context of the business logic of a Flask app, I'm writing *a ton* of these "definition" instances of a class, putting them in a list, and importing the list where needed. Outside of building it, the list is treated as static.

Simplified example:

**definitions.py**:

```
from my_object import MyObject

definition_registry = list()

# team 1, widget 1 definition
_definition = MyObject()
_definition.name = "team 1 widget 1"
_definition.coercer = str
definition_registry.append(_definition)

# team 1, widget 2 definition
_definition = MyObject()
_definition.name = "team 1 widget 2"
_definition.coercer = int
definition_registry.append(_definition)

# team 2, widget 1 definition
_definition = MyObject()
_definition.name = "team 2 widget 1"
_definition.coercer = float
definition_registry.append(_definition)
```

**my_object.py:**

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "unnamed"
        self.coercer = int

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MyObject instance: {self.name} / {self.coercer}"
```

**main.py**:

```
from definitions import definition_registry

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(definition_registry)
```

**Output:**

```
[MyObject instance: team 1 widget 1 / <class 'str'>, MyObject instance: team 1 widget 2 / <class 'int'>, MyObject instance: team 2 widget 1 / <class 'float'>]
```

How can I break up `definitions.py` into multiple files (`team_1.py`, `team_2.py`, ...)?

**Important caveat:** The instances of the real MyObject have to be defined in python. In my example the `coercer` attribute is meant as a placeholder to reinforce that fact.

I thought about using `exec`, but that's generally bad practice, and this doesn't feel like a good exception to that rule. For example, putting lines 5 to 9 of `definitions.py` into `team1w1.py` and replacing them with `exec(open(team1w1.py).read())` works but PyCharm's debugger doesn't execute `team1w1.py` line-by-line.

Another way would be to do something like

```
from team1w1 import definition
definition_registry.append(definition)

from team1w2 import definition
definition_registry.append(definition)
...
```

This is better but it still smells because

- `from ... import definition` repeated over and over in the same file
- `import MyObject` has to be repeated for every definition file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Search for code to implement plugins. Here is one way to do it:

Structure you code like so:

```
/myproject
    main.py
    my_object.py
    definitions/
        __init__.py
        team_1.py
        team_2.py
```

**main.py**

This is basically the same as your code with some extra code to show what is happening.

```
import sys

before = set(sys.modules.keys())

import definitions

after = set(sys.modules.keys())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('\nRegistry:\n')
    for item in definitions.registry:
        print(f"    {item}")
    print()

    # this is just to show how to access things in team_1
    print(definitions.team_1.foo)
    print()

    # this shows that the modules 'definitions', 'definitions.team_1',
    # and 'definitions.team_2' have been imported (plus others)
    print(after - before)
```

**my_object.py**

As others pointed out, `MyObject` could take the name and coercer as arguments
to `__init__()`, and the registry could be a class variable with registration handled by `__init__()`.

```
class MyObject:
    registry = []
    
    def __init__(self, name="unnamed", coercer=str):
        self.name = name
        self.coercer = coercer
        
        MyObject.registry.append(self)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MyObject instance: {self.name} / {self.coercer}"
```

**definitions/**init**.py**

This is the core of the technique.  When a package is imported, `__init__.py` gets run, such as when `main.py` has `import definitions`. The main idea is to use `pathlib.Path.glob()` to find all the files with names like `team_*` and import them using `importlib.import_module()`:

```
import importlib
import my_object
import pathlib

# this is an alias to the class variable so it can be referenced
# like definitions.registry
registry = my_object.MyObject.registry

package_name = __package__
package_path = pathlib.Path(__package__)

print(f"importing {package_name} from {__file__}")

for file_path in package_path.glob('team_*.py'):
    module_name = file_path.stem
    print(f"    importing {module_name} from {file_path}")
    importlib.import_module(f"{package_name}.{module_name}")

print("    done")
```

**definitions/team_1.py**

Needs to import `MyObject` to be able to create instances. Shows that there can be multiple `MyObjects` instantiated in the module, along with other things.

```
import pathlib
from my_object import MyObject

file_name = pathlib.Path(__file__).stem

print(f"        in {__package__}.{file_name}")

# assign the object (can get it through registry or as team_1.widget_1
widget_1 = MyObject("team 1 widget 1", str)

# don't assign the object (can only get it through the registry)
MyObject("team 1 widget 2", int)

# can define other things too (variables, functions, classes, etc.)
foo = 'this is team_1.foo'
```

**definitions/team_2.py**

```
from my_object import MyObject

print(f"        in {__package__}.{__file__}")

# team 2, widget 1 definition
MyObject("team 2 widget 1", float)
```

**Other stuff**

If you can't change `MyObject`, perhaps you can subclass it and use the subclass in `team_1.py`, etc.

Alternatively, define a `make_myobject()` factory function:

```
def make_myobject(name="unknown", coercer=str):
    definition = MyObject()
    definition.name = name
    definition.coercer = coercer
    registry.append(definition)
    return definition
```

Then `team_1.py` would look like:

```
from my_object import make_myobject

make_myobject("team 1 widget 1", int)

....
```

Lastly, `int`, `str`, and other types, classes, etc can be looked up by name.  So in your simplified example `MyObject()` or `make_myobject()` could take the name of a `coercer` and look it up.

```
import sys

def find_coercer(name):
    """Find the thing with the given name. If it is a dotted name, look
    it up in the named module. If it isn't a dotted name, look it up in
    the 'builtins' module.
    """
    module, _, name = name.strip().rpartition('.')

    if module == '':
        module = 'builtins'

    coercer = getattr(sys.modules[module], name)

    return coercer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyObject():

    all_instances = []

    def __init__(name, coercer):
        self.name = name
        self.coercer = coercer
        all_instance.append(self)
```

Your setup-program usage is

```
import MyObject

# Put your specifications into a readable list
widget_specs = [
    ["Team 1 widget 1", str],
    ["Team 1 widget 2", float],
    ...
]
for name, coercer in widget_specs:
    _ = MyObject(name, coercer)
```

Then you access `MyObject.all_instances` for your desired widget objects.

Will that solve the problem, or at least get you close enough?

Comment: Thanks but the point of my question is to break up `definitions.py` into multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I would structure it this way:

**myobject.py**

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, name="unnamed", coercer= int):
        self.name = name
        self.coercer = coercer

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MyObject instance: {self.name} / {self.coercer}"
```

**definitions.py**

```
# just done for 2 items - If you want to distribute those definitions, 
# you can define each element in a single file
teams = [{"name": "team 1 widget 1", "coercer": str}, {"name": "team 1 widget 2", "coercer": int}]

definition_registry = [MyObject(**element) for element in teams]
```

Comment: Thanks but the point of my question is to break up `definitions.py` into multiple files.